# regexp: match everything exept a single word

Tags: regex

I don't get how to create a regular expression that matches everything, except a fixed, single word. Can somebody help me?

Background: alias map for mailserver which redirects all mail to one user. `/.*/ -> user1` produces a redirection loop, so i need to exclude `user1` from the regexp.

Edit:

The regex should match *everything*, EXCEPT the single word *user1*. It should also match input that contains that word, i.e., *user11*.

i.e.: /.*/ without *user1*

Edit2:

POSIX Basic Regular Expressions

Comment: Can you give us some sample input text, and then describe what the expected output is?  Also, what regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen said, what Tool/programming language are you using? There's a lot of different RegEx out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with getting your value from the first group, you can use something like this:

```
(?:\buser1\b)?(.+?)(?:\buser1\b|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KgNfrM/1).

This will match anything before or after the word `user1` or everything if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` you can invert the match:

```
$ echo "user2
user3
user1" | grep -v '^user1$'
user2
user3
```

Or, with `sed` you can delete the match:

```
$ echo "user10
user2
user1" | sed -E '/^user1$/d'
user10
user2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^(?!user1$)`.
for checking purpose, you can use python as:

```
import re
if(re.match('^(?!user1$)','user11')):
  print('user11 matched')

if(re.match('^(?!user1$)','user1')):
  print('user1 matched')

if(re.match('^(?!user1$)','AnyThingElseBeforeuser1')):
  print('AnyThingElseBeforeuser1 matched')
```

the output is as you desire:

user11 matched

AnyThingElseBeforeuser1 matched